# Do you have to do reduction both ways to prove a problem is NPC?

Tags: np-complete, reductions

Also, what's the difference between transforming a problem into another problem and doing a reduction? They sound synonymous to me. Thank you!

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that a problem is NP-complete, you need to show two things:

1. The problem is NP-hard, i.e. it's at least as hard as any problem in NP
2. The problem is in NP, i.e. it's no harder than NP

Doing a reduction both ways is the easiest way to do this: reducing something in NP to a new problem shows that the new problem is NP-hard, and reducing your new problem to something in NP shows that the new problem is no harder than NP.

I've never heard "transforming" used formally, but I would guess from context it's the same as doing a polynomial-time reduction.

Comment: Does showing that a problem A can be verified in polynomial time and showing an unknown problem A is reducible to a known NPC problem B accomplish the same thing?

Comment: It does not. Suppose A is in P. Then A can be verified in poly time (by solving it) and A can be reduced to B in poly time (by solving A in poly time, then running B and ignoring the answer) but that doesn't make A NP-complete.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by Draconis is wrong in "showing that the new problem is NP-hard." Reducing from something in NP to a new problem does not show NP-hardness. In particular, if a problem A is in P it is also in NP. Suppose there is a reduction from such a polynomial-time solvable A to some new problem B. Then, problem B still can be in P, and in this case B is not NP-hard.

The correct version of this answer says that to show that a new problem is NP-hard one has to reduce from another NP**-hard** problem A. Then, the new problem cannot be "simpler" than the hardest problem in NP. If it were, then one could solve all NP-hard problems via the new problem, first reducing any problem to A (which is NP-hard by assumption) and then to B.